# getItem() Adapter method returning an object from other class

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

so basically my I am making an activity which has 2 fragments that we can navigate through using a viewPager. Each one of those 2 fragments has a listView and a CustomAdapter to populate those lists. Problem is the getItem(int) position in one of the adapters is returning an object of the second. (note that I am note using listFragments most of the answered questions are for listFragments)

here are the classes.

OrdersAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Hasan on 11/21/2016.
 */

public class OrdersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Order> {

    private int mColorResourceId;
    public OrdersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Order> orders, int colorResourceId) {
        super(context, 0, orders);
        mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Order getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item_order, parent, false);
        }
        Order currentOrder = getItem(position);
        TextView subjectTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.order_subject);
        subjectTextView.setText(currentOrder.getOrderSubject());
        TextView descriptionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.order_description);
        descriptionTextView.setText(currentOrder.getOrderDescription());
        TextView technicianNameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.technician_name);
        technicianNameTextView.setText( currentOrder.getTechnicainName());
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        ratingBar.getOnRatingBarChangeListener();
        View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
        textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

OrdersFragment.java

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrdersFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Order>> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final String QUERY = "";
    private OrdersAdapter ordersAdapter;


    public OrdersFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orders_list, container, false);

        ordersAdapter = new OrdersAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Order>(),R.color.category_orders);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(ordersAdapter);
        TextView noInternetView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noIntenet);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noInternetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Order order = ordersAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Order>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new OrdersLoader(getContext(), QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Order>> loader, List<Order> data) {
        ordersAdapter.clear();
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            ordersAdapter.addAll(data);
            ordersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Order>> loader) {
        ordersAdapter.clear();
        ordersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

OrdersLoader.java

```
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class OrdersLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Order>> {
    private String murl ;
    public OrdersLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        murl = url;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Order> loadInBackground() {

        if (murl == null) {
            return null;
        }
        URL url = UtilsOrders.createUrl(murl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = UtilsOrders.makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error closing input stream", e);
        }
        return UtilsOrders.extractOrders(jsonResponse);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

UserActivity.java

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewsAdapter adapter = new ViewsAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

ViewsAdapter.java

```
/**
 * Created by Hasan on 11/21/2016.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class ViewsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    public ViewsAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return "Technicians";
        } else
            return "Orders";

    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return new TechniciansFragment();
        } else
            return new OrdersFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

TechniciansAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * Created by Hasan on 11/21/2016.
 */

public class TechniciansAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Technician> {

        private int mColorResourceId;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Technician getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    public TechniciansAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Technician> technicians, int colorResourceId) {
            super(context, 0, technicians);
            mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item_technician, parent, false);
            }
            Technician currentTechnician = getItem(position);
            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.technician_name);
            nameTextView.setText(currentTechnician.getName());
            TextView ratePerHourTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.rate_per_hour);
            ratePerHourTextView.setText(currentTechnician.getRatePerHour() + "$ /hour");
            TextView phoneNumberTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.technician_phoneNumber);
            phoneNumberTextView.setText( currentTechnician.getPhoneNumber()+"");
            if(currentTechnician.hasCompany()){
                TextView companyTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
                companyTextView.setText(currentTechnician.getCompany());
            }
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            ratingBar.setRating(currentTechnician.getRating());
            View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
            textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);
            return listItemView;
        }
    }
```

TechniciansFragment.java

```
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class TechniciansFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Technician>> {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private final String QUERY = "";
    private TechniciansAdapter techniciansAdapter;


    public TechniciansFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.technicians_list, container, false);

        techniciansAdapter = new TechniciansAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Technician>(),R.color.category_technicians);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(techniciansAdapter);
        TextView noInternetView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noIntenet);
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            LoaderManager loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();
            loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this);
        } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noInternetView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Technician technician = techniciansAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<List<Technician>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new TechniciansLoader(getContext(), QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Technician>> loader, List<Technician> data) {
        techniciansAdapter.clear();
        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            techniciansAdapter.addAll(data);
            techniciansAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<List<Technician>> loader) {
        techniciansAdapter.clear();
        techniciansAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

TechniciansLoader.java

```
import android.content.AsyncTaskLoader;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Hasan on 8/6/2016.
 */
public class TechniciansLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<Technician>> {
    private String murl ;
    public TechniciansLoader(Context context, String url) {
        super(context);
        murl = url;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Technician> loadInBackground() {

        if (murl == null) {
            return null;
        }
        URL url = UtilsTechnician.createUrl(murl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = UtilsTechnician.makeHttpRequest(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Error closing input stream", e);
        }
        return UtilsTechnician.extractTechnicians(jsonResponse);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        forceLoad();
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.lebanesewebmasters.housemate, PID: 14346
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.lebanesewebmasters.housemate.Technician cannot be cast to com.lebanesewebmasters.housemate.Order
                      at com.lebanesewebmasters.housemate.OrdersAdapter.getItem(OrdersAdapter.java:30)
                      at com.lebanesewebmasters.housemate.OrdersAdapter.getView(OrdersAdapter.java:40)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
                      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
                      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2151)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1767)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:433)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15671)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5038)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2086)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Application terminated.
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Instead of posting all of your code, you should try to narrow down where the problem is. For instance, remove one of the fragments and see if the problem still exists. Or, attach the debugger and add some logs in `getItem()` to see what the object is.

Comment: Also, both of your loaders have the same ID. It might help if you made them different and then checked the ID in `onLoadFinished()` to make sure it's the right loader. I would define some IDs in XML so that it generates some `R.id` values.

Comment: when i remove one of the fragments , it works normally

Comment: and always the fragments that is not showing when first you enter this activity is the one giving the error at its listview adapter

Comment: Did you do anything about the loader IDs like I suggested?